# If I change a variable's value will the original value still exist inside the memory?

Tags: javascript

```
let a = 7;
a = 3;
console.log(a); // output 3
```

In this case, the value 7 is still inside a memory? I was reading that all primitive data types are immutable.

Comment: All primitives are immutable, i.e., they cannot be altered. It is important not to confuse a primitive itself with a variable assigned a primitive value. The variable may be reassigned a new value, but the existing value can not be changed in the ways that objects, arrays, and functions can be altered.   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive

Comment: @MisterJojo no, it means the value itself cannot be changed. You can "assign a new value" to your variable, but you can't change the value itself, unlike an array or object, which you can modify without affecting the variable binding.

Comment: In this case, you have replaced `7` with `3`. The value of `a` exists in memory but not `7`.

Comment: `a` gets replaced, whilst `let b = a`, changing `b` won't affect `a`, i.e *not passed by reference*, if `a` was an object it does, `let a = {a: '1'};let b = a;b.a = 2;console.log(a);` = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `a` is kept in memory, until garbage collection eventually recycles it. What the docs mean by immutable is that you can't directly alter the primative (in this case the integer 7). You can only replace the value.

There are examples on the docs but this is another one

```
let a = 1;
a.toString() // a is still 1, it cannot be mutated
```

However, we can assign this to another variable

```
let a = 1;
let b = a.toString() // b is string "1" and a remains as the integer 1
```

Or we can replace the value

```
let a = 1;
a = 10; // a is 10
```

Comment: "The value of a is kept in memory until garbage collection eventually recycles it." Please Could you explain to me this part better? Thanks

Comment: I think the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) may explain it better

Comment: var a =5; When we create a variable, it reserves a space for itself in the memory. The variable ‘a’ has space in memory that holds its value. When we try to change the value of ‘a’ by assigning another value like var a = 6, it doesn’t alter the value of the original a, it just creates a new variable ‘a’ with the new value 6. https://www.edureka.co/blog/data-types-in-javascript/   The memory address of a is different than before?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

Immutable is about the behaviour of the value, not about what happens when it's no longer being references: you cannot change an immutable value, you *have* to instead reassign your variable if you want it to point to a new value.

```
let b = 3;
let a = b; // the variable "a" points to the primitive value 3
b = 7;     // the variable "a" still points to the primitive value 3
a = 7;     // and now it points to a _different_ value. 7, in this case.
```

This is in contrast to things like arrays or objects, which you can change as much as you like without needing to reassign:

```
const obj = {};
const a = obj;
obj.cat = `meow`;
console.log(a); // this will show that "a" is { cat: "meow" }
```

We just changed the *content* of the value that "a" points to, without any reassignments.